# Why I cannot set other platforms when using Firemonkey Metropolis UI application?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

Testing the different options of platform targets i have found this information on the delphi xe5 help:

> Note: You cannot set OS X as the target platform for a Metropolis UI application.

[FireMonkey Metropolis UI Application](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/FireMonkey_Metropolis_UI_Application)

I have searched for more answers on that and could not find what is the real reason it is not permited.

I would like to have the same looking of the application on windows and android tablet. (I know that I can use a "regular" FMX app and make that other way, however I have no idea what are the restrictions, since I believed FMX should be always crossplatform, considering just plain FMX app)

EDIT: My final objective for my current project is to create an application with the look and feel of Win Metro, but not WinRT compatible, and use this app on Win32(XP/7/8) and Android Tablets. I dont want to follow ANY platform specific rules, only have the closest possible working behavior as the Delphi generated win32 application.

Comment: It is a little odd that you talk about OSX and then go on to say that you want consistent look and feel between Windows and Android.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan This help note about OSX lead me to test the android platform, that is my objective. And made me question myself since I believed that FMX projects where always crossplatform. I am trying to find what in the code does not permit that.

Comment: @eelias: Metro doesn't support mobile either. "Metropolis UI mobile applications (and WinRT) are not currently supported." Windows 32/64 desktop are the only supported targets whether it's FMX or VCL, AFAICT.

Comment: @KenWhite I am aware of that, I was trying the same look and feel, basically having the tiles and the buttons. I am doing that in java on android! I have a complete POS application that looks similar to Metro. However I wanted to use my codebase that is in Delphi and generate the same app in FMX. That just looks like as Metro. I am looking to understand what is the reason the Metropolis UI does not permit that, since it uses the plain FMX components.... Should I create a Metropolis project and do a copy and paste of the form in a new android app? I am missing something.

Comment: Create a mobile app and use the Metropolis theme. That's what you ask for. But the users will surely be better served by platform standard visuals. Your app will jar on android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metropolis UI is a hybrid system that uses IPC with a WinRT process. The WinRT process is used to display tiles and whatever else is needed over in WinRT land. This can only exist on a system that runs WinRT. Which means Windows 8 and not Mac or the mobile platforms.

It is true that you can build and run Metropolis UI apps on Windows 7 so clearly they can exist without the WinRT part. But the entire purpose on Metropolis UI is to be able to launch fake WinRT lookalike Delphi apps from the WinRT subsystem. So they don't really make sense anywhere else. I don't see any reason why Embarcadero would have invested effort making Metropolis UI apps work anywhere that does not have WinRT.

---

What you could do is use the style part of an FMX Metropolis UI project. That would give you the visual look that you are after. It would not be a Metropolis UI project, but would look as you wish. So you make a standard FMX desktop application targeting OSX. Then apply your chosen Metropolis style. This certainly works for desktop applications and I see no reason why it won't work for an Android tablet application.

Comment: This is not the answer to the question. Delphi (whether VCL or FMX) does not support WinRT, and therefore that can't affect whether OSX is a supported platform or not. Metro apps in Delphi are just styled with the look and feel (and gesture support) of the Metro UI.

Comment: @ken The Delphi compilers cannot produce WinRT executables but the Metropolis UI system relies on a WinRT app and IIPC

Comment: Not according to the XE5 docs. "Only Metropolis UI desktop applications are supported in XE3. Metropolis UI mobile applications (and WinRT) are not currently supported." Where do you see any reference to WinRT/IIPC in the VCL/FMX source for a Metro app? Also, there is an FMX style for Metro for the FMX Metro UI apps (C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\<n.n>\Redist\styles\Fmx). VCL styles are not involved in an FMX Metro app.

Comment: @ken http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Live_Tile_Support_for_Metropolis_UI_Applications

Comment: Question tagged XE5. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Developing_Metropolis_UI_Applications

Comment: @KenWhite Please elaborate

Comment: I did. See my first comment, my second comment, and the link in my third comment. VCL styles are not involved in FMX Metro UI apps, FMX is not dependent on WinRT, and neither are VCL metro apps.

Comment: @ken How are you going to run the live tiles and what not on OSX?

Comment: I didn't say you could run live tiles on OSX. Look at the source code for a Delphi VCL/FMX Metro UI app (of course, you'll need to find it for XE5 or XE6, a current version). Has nothing to do with actual Metro - it's a look and feel thing, not actual Metro. (I can build either FMX/VCL version, run on a Win7 machine that has no internet access, and it still works fine. No WinRT needed.)

Comment: @ken with a sodding great IPC link to the WinRT app that launches it

Comment: No. Win7, no WinRT or Win8 device in sight. Standard .exe file produced by Delphi IDE. Don't have a Win8/RT device - my stuff is all Android.

Comment: @ken the MO for metropolis is to be able to put Delphi apps on live tiles.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I see what Ken is saying. My understanding is that Metropolis UI is just a look and feel, no WinRT. I am interested in the look and feel, that I can do even in other languages etc. This is the reason of my question, why the Metropolis UI template application that is based on FMX is not compatible with android? (if it is not WinRT) what in the generated block that?

Comment: Not in **Delphi Metro UI**. It produces a look and feel user interface, not a true Metro app. Again, from the docs: "Metropolis UI is a set of features that produce **applications compatible with the look and feel** of the Microsoft® Windows 8 user interface." First sentence in the link I provided earlier.

Comment: @ken Correct. Delphi cannot make WinRT apps. Hence the separate WinRT process to do that part and do the IPC with the desktop Delphi app.

Comment: David, there is no **separate WinRT process** with a **Delphi** Metro UI app. It's a standard Win32 or Win64 executable; you can verify that yourself by examining the executable header. Single executable, runnable on a Win7 machine with no external access, devices, from a single EXE file. You're wrong here.  (You can also look at the source code.)

Comment: @ken There is. It is needed to do the part of the hybrid app that lives in WinRT land. Follow the link I gave above.

Comment: David, I can copy the application to a thumb drive, carry that thumb drive to a standalone machine that's never seen or heard of Delphi, run the **single** Windows executable, and use the Metro UI produced by Delphi. There is no *hybrid app** in a **Delphi** Metro UI app. Once again, you're wrong here. Try it yourself, or read the fine source code.

Comment: My answer says that too. I understand that the desktop part is just that. A Delphi desktop app. But the live tiles part has a WinRT app. It is described in the link I gave.

Comment: @ken actually the desktop part can be either vcl or FMX as it happens. I was mistaken asserting that it was vcl only. I have a feeling that was so for the first release but then again I could be wrong.

Comment: The link you provided requires addition of a TLiveTile component to your app, which is not part of the standard Metro UI app generated by the File->New application wizard for either FMX or VCL. It is not a feature of the standard application, and therefore isn't the reason for not supporting OSX. (It's in the Metropolis.UI.Tile unit, which isn't included in any of the generated files in a Metro UI app.)

Comment: @KenWhite Why would they go to the trouble of making Metropolis UI apps work on platforms where it was pointless. The entire rationale behind Metropolis UI was to let Delphi developers integrate with WinRT. Can we agree on that?

Comment: I'll agree that might have been part of the rationale. That brings up the question of why they bothered to make it available in FMX at all, when the VCL is the non cross-platform component library? It clearly wasn't intended to be cross-platform, as the docs clearly state it isn't for mobile or OSX.

Comment: @KenWhite I cannot explain that. It seems odd. In any case it's easy enough just to apply a Metropolis style to an FMX app and away you go. Thanks for your input here.

Comment: Metropolis UI was created so developers could create Win8 apps with the look and feel of RT. Possibly created so the marketing department could claim Win8 support. They are actually standard Win desktop apps so can run on Vista and Win7. There's a way to launch them from a live tile, but it's not a requirement of a Metropolis app.

Comment: Back to the question, I'd say crack open the Metropolis style of choice, remove the line that limits it to Windows apps and style your app with it.

Answer (score 2):

Different platforms use different backend frameworks and have different UI requirements. That is why you cannot add OSX to a Metro project (OSX is not a Metro platform), just like you cannot add OSX to a Mobile project (OSX is not a mobile platform) or a Mobile platform (iOS/Android) to a Desktop project (they are not desktop platforms).  Do not try to create a single *application* project that supports every UI platform that Delphi supports (a *package* project is a different matter - you can create multi-platform packages).  You will need to create separate projects - a Metro project for Metro UIs, a desktop project for desktop UIs, and a mobile project for mobile UIs.  You can share source files between them, but you should not share UI Forms between them.  Use platform-appropriate UIs instead.

Comment: But we can make an FMX app that targets 32 and 64 bit Windows and OSX all with the same codebase and the same forms using FMX. Pretty much the raison d'etre of FMX.

Comment: I totally agree with you. However I am in a project to use android tablet as a replacement for desktop windows. So for the standpoint of the user if closer to windows style better. I am looking for windows 8 style, but not WinRT, plain win32 on windows.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Windows and OSX are both desktop platforms, so they can co-exist in a single desktop app project.  You cannot add Win64 or OSX to a mobile project, for instance (you can add Win32 to a mobile app project, but only for debugging purposes), because they are not mobile platforms.  FMX is NOT a compile-once-and-run-everywhere kind of framework (like Java is, for instance), despite what the advertising tries to make you believe.  There is still some separation between the various platform projects that FMX supports.

Comment: @RemyLebeau based on what you said to David, can I have one project that target Win32, iOS tablet, Android Tablet that used exactly the same forms and code base? I want the look and feel of windows.

Comment: @eelias: No. A tablet is still a mobile platform, running a mobile OS.  As such, a tablet platform cannot be used in a desktop app  project, and vice versa.  You need separate projects.  They can share a common codebase, but not common UIs (unless you make the UIs in code with appropriate platform IFDEFs). Bringing a Windows look-and-feel to a tablet OS and vice versa is not a good idea, most users are not likely to appreciate that.  A tablet has its own look-and-feel based on its native OS, you should cater to that. Platform-specific consistency is important when dealing with UI form factors.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I can belive in you,  however WHY? I just made a test app that I have those 3 platforms and selecting win32 and running it show up the app. I dont see on all the documentation etc, what really makes the difference. What in the uses clause is not allowed, etc. (speaking generically about FMX)

Comment: I wasn't aware that what Remy says is the case. I thought you could make a project with all those targets and share ui. Not always a great idea mind you. But I thought it was possible. Is that not the case?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Not by default, no. If you really want to try it, you have to modify the .dproj file directly and add/enable the extra platforms in the `<Platforms>` section that are missing/disabled by default, and only then will the Project Manager *may* allow you to add those extra platforms to the project. The `<Platforms>` node tells the Project Manager which platforms it is allowed to work with, not which platforms are actually configured for compiling.  Those are managed in separate nodes of the .dproj file, so you still have to add the desired platforms to the project as needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, the most you can do (without hacking the dproj) is make a FMX Mobile application and add Win32 target to it.

Comment: @UweRaabe: yes, but again, adding Win32 to a mobile project is only for facilitating development by enabling debugging/simulation on a Win32 machine, you cannot actually deploy a mobile app to Win32.

Answer (score 1):

Just open the style(*.style) file in a text editor. And you will see some thing like :

```
PlatformTarget = '[MSWINDOWS][MODERN][DEFINEFONTSTYLES]'
```

And then just add the Platform you need.